# Force layout of tables

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am looking for working example of some code that does implement a force layout with tables.

I started with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MW8bB/):and I modified `addCircle` to show a single cell table. This works with static data. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thebruuu/ba6gu8os/3/)

But when I try to modify `addcircle` to get data as parameter it does not work as expected.

```
svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(addCircles)
    .call(force.drag);
```

I tried to add an `each` around the `addcircle` call, to pass selection data to it but no success...

Comment: Altocumulus may you pls give me some hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided jsFiddle code was in D3.js **v3**.
The code evolved to **v4**.